# Changing UISlider Images with Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm trying to change the default images for UISliders with Swift. I'm editing `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in `AppDelegate`.

In Objective C you would do this:

```
UIImage *maxImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"slider-track.png"];
[[UISlider appearance] setMaximumTrackImage:maxImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

I've tried converting to Swift but have not been successful:

```
var maxImage:UIImage = UIImage (named:"slider-track.png")
UISlider.setMaximumTrackImage(image: maxImage, forState: UIControlStateNormal)
```

The first line is fine, but the second gives an error.

What is the correct syntax for the second line?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[From Doc Example](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/UICatalog/Listings/Swift_UICatalog_SliderViewController_swift.html)

```
let leftTrackImage = UIImage(named: "slider_blue_track")
customslider.setMinimumTrackImage(leftTrackImage, for: .normal)
```

Comment: The page linked in your answer no longer exists.

Answer (score 11):

Changing UISlider thumb image with Swift

```
yourSlider.setThumbImage(UIImage(named: "yourSlider.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    yourSlider.setThumbImage(UIImage(named: "yourSlider.png"), forState: UIControlState.Highlighted)
```

Answer (score 3):

SWIFT 3

```
class Slider: UISlider {

    @IBInspectable var thumbImage: UIImage?

    // MARK: Lifecycle

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        if let thumbImage = thumbImage {
            self.setThumbImage(thumbImage, for: .normal)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**For Swift 3:**

```
 mySlider.setThumbImage(UIImage(named: "icon_slider_thumb.png"), for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Changing images fast using slider in swift4**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    //var slider1 = UISlider()


    var immgar = [UIImage(named: "bgspices.jpg"),UIImage(named: "index1.jpg"),  UIImage(named: "index2.jpg"),UIImage(named: "index3.jpg"),UIImage(named: "index4.jpg"), UIImage(named: "woods.jpg")]




                  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBOutlet weak var imageview: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!




    @IBAction func slider1(_ sender: Any) {


        print("changeImage method being called!!!!");

        let slider1 = Int(slider.value)
        imageview.image = immgar[slider1]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"slider"];

UIImage *trackImg;

if (isiPad) 
{

[[UISlider appearance] setThumbImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[UISlider appearance] setThumbImage:img forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
trackImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ipad_img.png"];
}
else 
{

 [[UISlider appearance] setThumbImage:[self imageWithImage:img scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(27, 27)] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[UISlider appearance] setThumbImage:[self imageWithImage:img scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(27, 27)] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
 trackImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"];
  }

[[UISlider appearance]  setMinimumTrackImage:trackImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[UISlider appearance]  setMaximumTrackImage:trackImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```